# Python turtle key listener unresponsive

Tags: turtle-graphics

So I'm relatively new to python graphics. I was loosely following a tutorial for space invaders and I can't get the key listeners to work. Any ideas why?

```
import turtle
import os
window = turtle.Screen()
player = turtle.Turtle()
move = 15


# sets up the window, background color and player sprite
def setup():
    window.bgcolor("black")
    window.title("Space Invaders")

    player.color("red")
    player.shape("triangle")
    player.penup()
    player.speed(0)
    player.setposition(0, -250)
    player.setheading(90)


# controls left and right movement
def move_left():
    player.setx(player.xcor() - move)
    print("left")


def move_right():
    player.setx(player.xcor() + move)
    print("right")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup()
    window.onkey(move_left(), "Left")
    window.onkey(move_right(), "Right")
    window.listen()
    turtle.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure but I think that you should take the

```
window.onkey(move_left(), "Left")
window.onkey(move_right(), "Right")
```

out of the if statement because that could be the issue.
If that doesn't work try it getting rid of the () like this...

```
window.onkey(move_left, "Left")
window.onkey(move_right, "Right")
```

If that doesn't work take everything inside of the setup function outside of it.

That's really all I can say but if all that fails follow the tutorial more closely. also I found these 2 things that might help alot.
[Python, Turtle Graphics, Key bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867731/python-turtle-graphics-key-bindings?rq=1)
and also this
[Make key bindings work for Space Invaders game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56464830/make-key-bindings-work-for-space-invaders-game?rq=1)

Comment: I figured this out this morning. Didn't realize that python turtle was so picky.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess as I'm not that expert with turtle but probably one of the two

1- You should use the windows.listen() method before windows.onkey() method.

2- You should add a while loop that is always set to true (but i guess thats what turtle.mainloop()) does?

Comment: I tried this and it still didn't work. The loop isn't necessary due to the turtle.mainloop()